# Mongo db error getting Error validating $lookup value. err=$lookup against an expression value is not allowed in this atlas tier

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am creating express server for the project and I used the mongodb for the database. I am getting error,

```
Error validating $lookup value. err=$lookup against an expression value is not allowed in this atlas tier.
```

movies schema,

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
const MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    desc: { type: String },
    img: { type: String },
    imgTitle: { type: String },
    imgSm: { type: String },
    trailer: { type: String },
    video: { type: String },
    year: { type: String },
    limit: { type: Number },
    genre: { type: String },
    isSeries: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("movies", MovieSchema);
```

My lists schema,

```
const ListSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    type: { type: String },
    genre: { type: String },
    content: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, ref: "movies" },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

`lists schema` has a `content` property and it's contains the `id`s of the `movies`.so I need to have get all `movies` in the `list` with `sample` size 4,so I write `aggregation` for the list schema for populating movies object in `content` property in `list schema`. So where is the bug in my code ?I hope your help!
so I coded it as,

```
   const list = await List.aggregate([
            { $sample: { size: 4 } },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "$movies",
                foreignField: "_id",
                localField: "content",
                as: "content",
              },
            },
          ]);
        }
        res.status(200).json(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be "movies" not "$movies"

Comment: I suggest you to answer using samples or the same code with a snippets of code modified